# how to use Maps with groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

Tags: templates, jenkins, groovy

Im unsure how to use Maps with a template engine. Can someone tell me what im doing wrong here?

```
def engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine() 
def binding = [jobs:[[name:'job1',action:'build'], [name:'job2', action:'build']]]
def text = '''
println ${jobs}
println ${jobs[0].name}
${jobs}.each{ job ->  
    println "name " + job.name 
}

'''
def template = engine.createTemplate(text).make(binding)
println template
```

produces this output

```
Result
println [[name:job1, action:build], [name:job2, action:build]]
println job1
[[name:job1, action:build], [name:job2, action:build]].each{ job ->  
    println "name " + job.name 
}
```

The 2nd `println` shows `job1` from this `${jobs[0].name}` which looks good except I want to do that in the iterator, but I'm not sure what that `each` is showing me. I would expect to get

```
name job1
name job2
```

from the iterator. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all from documentation: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/text/SimpleTemplateEngine.html

```groovy
def engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine() 
def binding = [jobs:[[name:'job1',action:'build'], [name:'job2', action:'build']]]
def text = '''
jobs[0].name = ${jobs[0].name}
<% jobs.each{ job -> %>\
   name = ${job.name}
<%}%>
'''
def template = engine.createTemplate(text).make(binding)
println template
```

result:

```
jobs[0].name = job1
   name = job1
   name = job2
```

Comment: Thank you @dagnett for clearing that up. I didnt see a specific text embeded iterator example in [the documentation](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html) but you could guess at how to use it. In contrast [JSP wiki pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) 1st example is an iterator.